# Stop Eclipse from cutting code lines on clean up

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, coding-style, code-cleanup

In Eclipse I want (for example) that code like *this*

```
public Foo bar() {

}
```

gets formatted to *this*

```
public Foo bar()
{

}
```

via the clean up function.



But to do that I have to check "Format source code" in the clean up profile.
But that also formats code like *this*

```
alert.setHeaderText("blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla");
```

to *this*

```
alert.setHeaderText(
"blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla");
```

which I absolutely do not want. Is there any possible way to stop Eclipse from cutting lines like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the style to which code is formatted. Under

Preferences: Java -> CodeStyle -> Formatter

Then look for "Line wrapping".

Answer (score 3):

Go to Window->Preferences->Java->Code Style->Formatter. Create new formatter. Click on edit and then pick tab Line Wrapping and set Line Wrapping policy to Do not wrap.

For more clarification refer the below Link :-

http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/07/09/invisible-chaos-mastering-white-spaces-in-eclipse/

Comment: The default formatting looks Great which Eclipse providing, best to follow this Url content.